# Open Graph insights for specific post

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

We have a Facebook Application with custom Open Graph objects and actions.

We then use a App Access Token to post stories for a particular user from our backend with the normal Open Graph REST API. After the post-call succeeds we log the returned "id" of that post.

Now we would like to collect insight data (e.g. post_impressions_unique) for some of these individual posts/stories using the logged id's.

According to https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/573/ we should be able to do something like:

https://graph.facebook.com/[POST ID]/insights

Even though this call seems to work using our normal App Access Token, no insight data is returned for the post/story.

Does anyone know if this is possible and how to do it?

We have been experimenting with a normal User Access Token and the "read_insights" permissions, but with no luck. I have read some similar questions but mainly regarding page-posts (this is an App Open Graph post/story).

EDIT:
The facebook article above only refers to "Page" posts. I'm looking for analytics on individual Facebook App Opengraph Posts/stories. It seems difficult to find any good information about this, has nobody attempted this with any success?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You must add insights into a permissions/Extended permissions

Article :

**Getting Page Insights**

In order to obtain Page Insights via the Graph API, you must use a Page access token, and you must have the read_insights permission. Click on the link below to see this working in the Graph API Explorer.

Comment: We are not in the App Center, we are a normal web-site which uses Facebooks Oauth login dialog. Do we need to request "read_insights" from all users logging into our application? Isn't that if that perticular users wants to read insight data? We would like to read insight data from our App Access Token (from our backend).

Comment: "Do we need to request "read_insights" from all users logging into our application?" - Yes you need this.

Read again article(ps://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/573/) and you will find this : 

"In order to obtain Page Insights via the Graph API, you must use a Page access token, and you must have the read_insights permission. Click on the link below to see this working in the Graph API Explorer."

Comment: This is not really clear though since they are talking about a permission for the Page Access Token, not a User Access Token. We use normal User Access Tokens for all users of our site and the "publish_stream" permission to be able to publish the stories/posts through open-graph actions with our App Access Token. We are not using Page Access Tokens or page-stories, so maybe this article is not valid for us? Has anybody had success in reading insight data for a specific post/story on a Facebook web application?

Comment: Sorry maybe you understand me wrong : 
publish_stream and public_actions you not need in your app, i add read_insignits in real my application to show where you must to add this permission. 

Only you need to add read_insights now is clear ?

Comment: I added the "read_insights" to the Permissions page on App Setting, but i doesn't seem to make any difference to my requests on [POST-ID]/insights. The "data" vector in the response is still empty. I think the setting on that page is for User-logins through the App Center which is not applicable to me.